# (Ola Hallengren) Deleting transaction log backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

We're using Ola's script to run weekly full, nightly diff and hourly transaction logs. All the jobs are correctly creating their backups, and the full and diff jobs are cleaning up after a week, transaction logs are set to clean up after 48 hours (we backup the NAS that the files are stored on nightly so these files are still accessible if we need them, they're just out of the way).

I'm finding transaction logs on certain databases aren't cleaning up, ie when I look at the file-system I can find transaction logs from a month ago dating right forward to today. The only reason I could think for this  is if a more recent diff backup doesn't exists, but they do, and they've not been moved to a different directory. None of the jobs are recording any any kind of failure triggered manually or running from the schedule. The other jobs are running and cleaning up just fine, ruling out permission issues (I've also checked on the NAS, the SQL server agent has Full Control).

Current step being run by the log backup job:

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'\\server\folder\', @BackupType = 'LOG', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 48, @CheckSum = 'Y', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

Here's the Diff job that cleans up just fine for comparison

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'\\servername\folder', @BackupType = 'DIFF', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 192, @CheckSum = 'Y', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

Does anyone know  more about how the job checks for the presence of the a full or diff backup? Or any other reason this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add more details on why you think the scripts aren't cleaning up well? For starters: A list of your backup files on disk might help to find out why your files aren't being cleaned up.

Comment: Sure I'll edit it in.

Comment: What parameter settings are you using in the job steps?

Comment: Any chance the file permissions have been changed so the the credentials being used now dont have permission?

Comment: I second Peter's statement about permissions; confirm the SQL Agent user on your server has Full Control of the NAS folders.

Comment: Confirm the log job has a @CleanupTime = 48 clause. You might edit the post to include your job's command text. Also, post the log text file this job generates, as it may offer additional clues.

Comment: Hi, thanks guys, I've edited in the code run for the log job and the diff job (diff is working fine, just for comparison to show the agent has permissions).

Comment: I've never done native SQL backups, but if I had this problem i would first identify the files I believe should be deleted and then run parts of the raw code to identify those files and figure out why they aren't being identified or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and ran the latest version of Ola's scripts and I'm no longer having the issue. Thanks to all responders! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you are only providing information on the differential and transaction log backup steps of the backup procedure. What is with the FULL backup?

Ola has implemented a fail-safe mechanism which will delete transaction log backups only if a FULL and/or DIFF backup is available.

> DatabaseBackup has a check to verify that transaction log backups that are newer than the most recent full or differential backup are not deleted.

<sub>***Reference:*** [SQL Server Backup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) (from ola.hallengren.com)</sub>

This means that if you don't have a recent FULL or DIFF backup, then the `@CleanupTime` parameter will have no effect. All the Transaction Log backups will be kept on disk, even though the `CleanupTime` has passed.

You might want to check if your FULL, DIFF and TLOG backups are consistent and available on disk. It is important to have all files available. sequence available.

## Example of Files on Disk

Assuming it is Friday 3.30pm (what a coincidence) you should find the following files in your backup folder if everything is set up correctly:
<sub>(I have put a separator between the FULL and DIFF backups)</sub>

```
SA | 1900 | FULL
----------------
SU | 1800 | DIFF
----------------
MO | 1800 | DIFF
----------------
TU | 1800 | DIFF
----------------
WE | 1800 | DIFF 
----------------
WE | 1800 | TLOG
WE | 1900 | TLOG
WE | 2000 | TLOG
WE | 2100 | TLOG
WE | 2200 | TLOG
WE | 2300 | TLOG
WE | 2400 | TLOG
TH | 0100 | TLOG
TH | 0200 | TLOG
TH | 0300 | TLOG
TH | 0400 | TLOG
TH | 0500 | TLOG
TH | 0600 | TLOG
TH | 0700 | TLOG
TH | 0800 | TLOG
TH | 0900 | TLOG
TH | 1000 | TLOG
TH | 1100 | TLOG
TH | 1200 | TLOG
TH | 1300 | TLOG
TH | 1400 | TLOG
TH | 1500 | TLOG
TH | 1600 | TLOG
TH | 1700 | TLOG
----------------
TH | 1800 | DIFF
----------------
TH | 1800 | TLOG
TH | 1900 | TLOG
TH | 2000 | TLOG
TH | 2100 | TLOG
TH | 2200 | TLOG
TH | 2300 | TLOG
TH | 2400 | TLOG
FR | 0100 | TLOG
FR | 0200 | TLOG
FR | 0300 | TLOG
FR | 0400 | TLOG
FR | 0500 | TLOG
FR | 0600 | TLOG
FR | 0700 | TLOG
FR | 0800 | TLOG
FR | 0900 | TLOG
FR | 1000 | TLOG
FR | 1100 | TLOG
FR | 1200 | TLOG
FR | 1300 | TLOG
FR | 1400 | TLOG
FR | 1500 | TLOG
```

## Possible Reasons TLOG Files Aren't Deleted

### Ola's Failsafe Mechanism

If a DIFF backup is missing (for example the DIFF from WE and TH) then no TLOG backups will be deleted from disk up until the last DIFF or FULL backup. In this example you would have TLOG backup files up until the DIFF backup on **TU**esday at 6pm (1800).

**Solution**

1. Ensure you have FULL and DIFF backups on disk.

### "SQL Server Agent" Service Account Insufficient Privileges

If the **SQL Server Agent (INSTANCE)** Service Account doesn't have enough privileges on the directory it is deleting files from, then it will be unable to delete the TLOG backup files.

**Solution**

1. Ensure the Windows Account of the SQL Server Agent Service has access to the network drive.
2. Check that the **Run As** setting in the job step is set to the **SQL Server Agent Service Account**.

### SQL Server Agent Jobs Not Being Logged in Msdb

There are cases then the job steps of jobs executing are unable to enter the details into the **msdb** job tables due to contention (locks, blocks, long running transactions). The tables required by the backup job are being locked by another process (another maintenance plan / other 3-rd party tools / cleanup jobs / **a long running transaction**) and might be determined as the victim of a deadlock and rolled back. The data is missing in the **msdb** database and because **no FULL or DIFF backups exist**, nothing gets deleted.

Ola checks this with the following part in the `DatabaseBackup` stored procedures:

> ```
>     IF @CurrentBackupType = 'LOG' AND (@CleanupTime IS NOT NULL OR @MirrorCleanupTime IS NOT NULL)
>     BEGIN
>       SELECT @CurrentLatestBackup = MAX(backup_finish_date)
>       FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
>       WHERE ([type] IN('D','I')
>       OR database_backup_lsn < @CurrentDifferentialBaseLSN)
>       AND is_damaged = 0
>       AND database_name = @CurrentDatabaseName
>     END
> ```

This means that if the record for the previous DIFF or FULL backup was unable to be recorded in the **msdb** database, then the TLOG files will never be deleted.

**Special Solution**

1. Check that the FULL and/or DIFF backups of the database in question are recorded in the **msdb** database and verify that you don't have any long running transactions on the msdb database.
2. Reschedule (the/other) jobs to run at a slightly different times if you have multiple jobs running at the same time.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
The Full and Diff backup files all exist in the correct directory, and are cleaning up OK.

The Windows account of the SQL Server Agent has Full Control on the target directory and the step is set to Run As SQL Server Agent.

I've queried msdb.dbo.backupset  and all the backups that I expect to exist are showing up (hourly logs, nightly diffs and weekly full).

Comment: Thanks for responding back. I'll give it another thought or two and let you know if I come up with a new solution/idea. Quick one: You had a look at the directory permissions and found everything to be ok. What do the permissions on the files look like? Does the SQL Server Agent Job Service Account (long word that) have permissions on the individual TLOG backup files themselves?

Comment: Yeah the permissions were fine down to file level. I've ended up downloading the latest version of Ola's script and now I'm not having the issue anymore :/ which is good 'cause it's working, but I don't know why it was happening and now never will. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be going on here.

### The files are in the wrong place, or have an unexpected extension

This one seems unlikely, since you've probably been using Ola's scripts for all your backups, but just in case you've changed a setting (like the directory location, or the log file extension).

The "cleanup" part of Ola's scripts are looking for backups in this location (starting with the server / folder you specified in the @Directory parameter).  In your question you used `@Directory = N'\\server\folder\'` so I'll continue with that:

```
\\server\folder\{ServerName}${InstanceName}\{DatabaseName}\LOG
```

If this is a default (not named) instance, you can ignore the `$InstanceName` part.

If the files you want to be deleted are not in this folder, and don't have a .trn extension, then they won't be deleted by the cleanup step.

### Something is "touching" your log backup files

The `xp_delete_file` extended stored procedure date parameter deletes based on the "modified date" metadata.  If some other application has "touched" these files, causing Windows to update the modified date to a time inside the cutoff, they won't be deleted.

### There is a permissions issue

The account that's running SQL Server Agent Services should have full control on the folder where backups are to be deleted.  Make sure this hasn't been changed.

### Validation checks are failing or other problems occurred

I noticed you have `@LogToTable = 'Y'` - you should check to confirm there are no error messages being reported during these times.